# Bash IF exit code redirect errors

Tags: bash, if-statement, redirect, scripting, exit-code

I'm writing a bash script right now that has a statement to check if a directory contains stuff.

Right now, the code is

```
if [ "$(ls -A $APPLICATIONS)"  ]; then
    do something
else
    do something else
fi
```

However, when the folder is indeed empty, I would like the error from ls to be suppressed. Normally, it would say "No such file or directory," but I want to redirect that to /dev/null.

I've tried doing

```
if [ "$(ls -A $APPLICATIONS &> /dev/null)"  ]; then
```

That does redirect everything to /dev/null like I wanted, but it also causes the directory to not be found (essentially causing exit code 1).

What would be the right way to do this?

Comment: An empty directory shouldn't cause an error. You'll only get that error if the directory itself doesn't exist, not if it's empty.

Comment: Unless `$APPLICATIONS` contains a wildcard, e.g. `/path/to/directory/*` rather than just the directory name.

Comment: @Barmar Turns out another facet of the issue is my location where the directory was supposed to be was having it's own issues. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&>` redirects both `stdout` and `stderr`. To redirect only `stderr`, use `2>`.

```
if [ "$(ls -A $APPLICATIONS 2> /dev/null)"  ]; then
```

Comment: Whoops. There we go. That's the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Where does `APPLICATIONS` come from? And what is it set to when you're running your script?

I have found that the best way to run an if statement against a command is to do the following:

```
if command; then
    do something
fi
```

In your case you can do the following assuming `APPLICATIONS` is in the format `/path/to/folder` or `local/folder`:

```
#!/bin/bash

APPLICATIONS="$1"

[[ -z "$APPLICATIONS" ]] && exit 1    # Exit if APPLICATIONS is not set.

if ls -A -- "$APPLICATIONS"/* &>/dev/null; then
    echo do something    # Directory is not empty
else
    echo do something else     # Directory is empty
fi
```

Comment: It doesn't run the output of the `ls` command because it's being used as the argument to `test`.

Comment: Good point, without the square brackets would attempt to execute it. I'll modify my answer.